# Determine average rate of change of function

Tags: calculus

How to determine the average rate of change of $f(x)= x^5-3x^4$ on the interval $[-2,4]$

Comment: change in $f(x)$ divided by change in $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for the average rate of change of a function $f(x)$ can be expressed as

$A(x)= \dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$

Just set your $f(x)=f(4)$ and $f(a)= f(-2)$ 
and $x=4$ and $a=-2$

Then you should have $A(x)= 272/6$ or $136/3$